# Getting unknown error while running an Grails 2.1.1 application using grials run-app

Tags: hibernate, grails, javabeans, grails-2.1

I am getting Hibernate error of not able to create the required bean while running a Grails 2.1.1 app using grails run-app command.

The stack trace of the error is given below:

> Loading Grails 2.1.1 | Configuring classpath. | Environment set to
>   development..... | Packaging Grails application.... | Compiling 1
>   source files | Compiling 1 source files..... | Running Grails
>   application Configuring Spring Security UI ... ... finished
>   configuring Spring Security UI Configuring Spring Security Core ...
>   ... finished configuring Spring Security Core Configuring Spring
>   Security ACL ... ... finished configuring Spring Security ACL
>   Configuring Spring Security Twitter ... ... finished configuring
>   Spring Security Twitter
>
> | Error 2013-08-30 16:24:31,120 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException:
>   **Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!**
>
> Message: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference
>   to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': **Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException:
>   Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!**
>               Line | Method
>           ->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
>          - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>           |    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
>           |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>           |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>           ^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException:
>   Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
>
> ```
> ->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
>   - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
>   |    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
>   |   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
>   |    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
>   ^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
> ```
>
> Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property
>   'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property
>   'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException:
>   Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!

**Settings of my *DataBaseConfig*.groovy is as below:**

```
  dataSource {
  pooled = true
  driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
  username = "sa"
  password = ""
}
hibernate {
cache.use_second_level_cache = true
cache.use_query_cache = false
cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}

    // environment specific settings
  environments {

development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
}
test {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
}
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
}
```

An early response is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293763/grails-suddenly-throws-error-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database). It seems it might be related to your jdk version

Answer (score 0):

Have experienced the same problems.

The issue seems to be related to the version of grails you are running.
for versions of jdk 1.7.025> on grails below version 2.2.3 this seems to appear.

We degraded to a lower version of the jdk and the problems did not appear.