# Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!

Tags: grails, spring-boot, grails-orm, nuodb

I am trying to build a groovy project based on gorm, with NuoDB. But getting this error - **Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!**

The weird thing is that it works with mysql. So my initial suspect was database configuration for NuoDB, but I checked and re-checked the configuration parameters, as per provided here [NuoDB Docs](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/Connecting-to-a-Database-Using-Java-Hibernate-Driver.htm)

I also upgraded **grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4** version to 3.1.1.RELEASE from 1.1.0, as discussed here for same issue with [SOF Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293763/grails-suddenly-throws-error-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database)

The application I'm building is based on the example presented for using gorm standalone (without grails) - [github link](https://github.com/rimerosolutions/gorm-standalone-example-2_4_x)

I am not able to understand if the problem is due to some specific grails version, or due to nuodb. Is it possible that grails/gorm does not support NuoDB yet ?

My application.properties -

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoHibernateDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:com.nuodb.hib://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
#spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect=com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect
#spring.datasource.dialect=com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect
hibernate.dialect:com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect
hibernate.show_sql:true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto:create
entitymanager.packagesToScan:com.myPackage
cache.provider_class =net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
```

I tried experimenting with various key values for the dialect parameter, but none actually worked.

My build.gradle -

```
enter buildscript {
repositories {
maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-release" }
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
   classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.9.RELEASE")
 }
}
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

repositories {
   maven  {
     url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
 } 
}

dependencies {
   compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
   //compile("org.grails:gorm-hibernate4-spring-boot:1.1.0.RELEASE")
   compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.1.RELEASE"
   //runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
   runtime 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc'
   runtime group: 'com.nuodb.jdbc', name: 'nuodb-jdbc', version: '2.3.1'
   runtime group: 'com.nuodb.hibernate', name: 'nuodb-hibernate', version: '2.3.1'
   testCompile ('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.3') {
   exclude module: "junit-dep"
   exclude module: "groovy-all"
  }
  testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
  testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.3')
  testCompile("junit:junit")
 }

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
   gradleVersion = '2.1'
}
```

The Error Logs StackTrace :

```
2016-09-23 13:28:08.333  INFO 6228 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-23 13:28:08.346  INFO 6228 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-09-23 13:28:27.309  WARN 6228 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.orange.kbu.domain.ApiDataValidator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.orange.kbu.Application2.main(Application2.groovy:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1439)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:875)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:265)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:650)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:381)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:367)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:126)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:384)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.support.HibernateDialectDetectorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateDialectDetectorFactoryBean.java:116)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
... 77 common frames omitted

2016-09-23 13:28:27.359  INFO 6228 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: []
2016-09-23 13:28:27.359  INFO 6228 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-09-23 13:28:27.361 ERROR 6228 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.orange.kbu.domain.ApiDataValidator': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at com.orange.kbu.Application2.main(Application2.groovy:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1439)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:875)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:265)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:502)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:491)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:650)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:381)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:367)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:126)
at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:106)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:384)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:165)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please add complete error log.

Comment: @Abhinandan Added the Logs.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to provide hibernate dialect definition via a Config.groovy.
At least that helped me. If you take a look into HibernateDialectDetectorFactoryBean source code:

```
            ConfigObject config = grailsApplication != null ? grailsApplication.getConfig() : null;
            Properties properties = config != null ? config.toProperties() : new Properties();
            hibernateDialect = DialectFactory.buildDialect(properties, connection);
            hibernateDialectClassName = hibernateDialect.getClass().getName();
```

DialectFactory requires property *hibernate.dialect* which obviously could be defined in your config. Another question is that dialect class should exist!
DialectFactory factory either constructs dialect from the provided *dialectName* OR tries to determine it from registered DIALECT_RESOLVERS.

I have provided *org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect* through the config and was able to start application on Oracle 12 in my personal case (old hibernate doesn't not have Oracle12Dialect). Hope that helps and I'm not mistaken.

Another solution is to define beans and use your own *applicationContext-hibernate.xml*, just put a stub into DataSource.groovy

```
dataSource { dialect = 'any existing dialect name' }
```

Unfortunately without that stub you will not be able to start.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the example and tried to run it, unmodified, on NuoDB.
I had problems getting the DataSource defined, so I need to convince SpringBoot to use the nuodb datasource.

You have clearly got past that point.

My initial suggestion would be for you to try a more recent version of NuoDB.

From the NuoDB documentation pages, NuoDB 2.3, 2.4, and 2.5 all provide JDBC 4.0 compliant drivers, and all support Hibernate 3.6.6 and 4.1.x.

However, it wold be a simple thing to install NuoDB 2.4 or 2.5, and run your test against that.

Edit-1: Ok, I've got a bit further with this.

Firstly, if you haven't already done so, then you should run your Gradle build with the "--debug" switch - as this suggestion - buried deep in the error output - suggests:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration
>   report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)

Secondly, I have not yet found a way to get any property key for "hibernate.dialect" to be recognised.
I've tried: "hiberntate.dialect" and "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect.

Thirdly, I tried providing the HibernateDialect bean manually - which worked ... partially.

I added the following as an inner class to the Application.groovy class:

```
  @Configuration
  static class Config {

     @Bean
     Dialect hibernateDialect() {
        return new com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect();
     }
  }
```

I needed the following imports:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
```

The result is puzzling/annoying:
I get a pleasing INFO message:

> INFO 50403 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>   : HHH000400: Using dialect: com.nuodb.hibernate.NuoDBDialect

... but the application still fails with exactly the same error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException:
>   Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [NuoDB]!

So it appears that just providing a hibernateDialect bean is not enough, and GORM is still insisting on using a hibernateDialectDetector; which is still failing to detect the NuoDB hibernate dialect object - despite the database product name being "NuoDB", and the dialect class being "NuoDBDialect".

Finally, I've tried creating an instance of HibernateDialectDetectorFactoryBean, but that doesn't seem to even be resolved - so I suspect that GORM doesn't in fact dependency-inject that *sigh*.

Cheers!
Nik

Comment: Thanks for your help.. The good-looking info log and, then the same error is really weird, now that gives me a doubt about gorm compatibility with NuoDB. I'll give it a try myself again, adding the dialect bean manually, and maybe then I can try to get some support by reporting an issue on gorm's github repo...