# Grails 2.3.4 not working running the app

Tags: grails

I created a new project with

Grails 2.3.4
Java JDK 1.7.0_45
ubuntu 13.10 64 bits
2gb ram

When I run the command:

grails run-app

see the following errors:

```
| Error 2014-01-11 10:49:49,007 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
    Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.exceptions.CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CouldNotDetermineHibernateDialectException: Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

i dont know whats happen with this...please help

Comment: Have you changed something in data source file

Comment: Make sure you are using hibernate 3. Delete the target folder and try to run grails again.

Comment: im using hibernate 3 and i dont change anything in the data source file...the error still there

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using JAVA_HOME set to oracle jdk and not to open jdk. I'm working with your same enviroment and i have no problem. Probably this post [stackoverflow.com/questions/17293763](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293763/grails-suddenly-throws-error-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database) even if grails is a bit older than grails 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]! # or PostgresSQL if postgres is used
```

check out :

[Grails suddenly throws error Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293763/grails-suddenly-throws-error-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database)

Replacing OpenJDK 1.7.x with OpenJDK 1.6.x seems to have solved it for me (Ubuntu 13.04).

[How do I avoid 'Could not determine Hibernate dialect for database name [H2]!'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336107/how-do-i-avoid-could-not-determine-hibernate-dialect-for-database-name-h2)

My solution is, in your DataSource.groovy, use this

dialect='org.hibernate.dialect.H2DialectPatch'